# cross compiler works compiling app but not kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cross-compiling

I compiled a cross tool for arm with ct-ng. I tested it by compiling a hello.c just printing "hello world", and downloaded it to a working board, it worked.
But using it to compile a kernel, and downloading to the board, the kernel failed booting. The root file system was compiled by the same cross tool.

The tool's combination is:
kernel-2.26.32.61
gcc-4.8.1
glibc-2.17
binutils-2.22
gdb-7.4.1

The working kernel version is 2.26.31.2. I use the cross tool to compile kernel 2.6.32.61. I am sure the kernel source and the busybox source work will,  because compiling them by a cross tool arm-linux-gcc 4.3.2 downloads from the Internet and everything works.(I use busybox to make a root fs.)

Is it the problem caused by the same kernel's version?

I check what i do but still can not find out.

From the serial output, the first error it says "Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000001 \n pgd = c0004000".

From the System.map, i find "c0004000" map to  "A swapper_pg_dir".

And i note that the bad kernel compiling by my cross tool is a litter smaller than the working one, only 3664B. But i do not know what the actual missing.

Comment: I do the same with newer Linux kernels and it works; so I suspect Linux patches are needed to work with a newer optimization.  I would use 4.8.2, though.  Do you know where it fails?  Follow [this advice](http://www.lpcware.com/content/forum/linux-early-boot-debug) and give the serial output when Linux boots with the 4.8.1 compiler.

Comment: I check what i do but still can not find out. From the the serial output, the first error it says "Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 00000001 \n pgd = c0004000". From the System.map, i find "c0004000" map to  "A swapper_pg_dir".

Answer (score 0):

Once I had similar issue for kernel written for 4.6, but built with 4.8. Fixed with adding cflag -ffreestanding to KBUILD_CFLAGS. Maybe it's your case as well?